# How do I access all elements to my array that i'm pointing at and change them during a mergeSort function call?

Tags: c++

I have a mergeSort function that I have tested and it works when I have the function in main(). I'm trying to implement it into a class right now but when I print out the array elements after sorting it, they are not sorted. I think that my problem lies in how I'm accessing my array elements, and what I'm doing with them.

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Sort.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {

    Sort temp(10);

    temp.InitArray();

    cout << "Unsorted: ";
    temp.Print();

    temp.MergeSort(0, 9);

    cout << "Sorted: ";
    temp.Print();

    cout << "end" << endl;
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Sort.h

```
#ifndef __SORT__
#define __SORT__

class Sort
{
public:
    Sort(int arraySize);
    ~Sort();

    void InitArray();
    void MergeSort(int low, int high);
    void Print();
private:
    int *myArray;
    int size;

    void MergeSortRecursionHelper(int indexL, int indexM, int indexH);
};

#endif
```

Sort.cpp

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>
#include "Sort.h"

Sort::Sort(int arraySize){
    myArray = new int[arraySize];
    size = arraySize;
}

Sort::~Sort(){
    delete [] myArray;
}

void Sort::InitArray() {
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        myArray[i] = rand() % 100;
    }
}
void Sort::MergeSort(int low, int high) {
    //base case
    if(myArray[high] <= myArray[low]){
        return;
    }
    int mid = (low + high) / 2;
    MergeSort(low, mid);
    MergeSort(mid + 1, high);

    MergeSortRecursionHelper(low, mid, high);
}

void Sort::MergeSortRecursionHelper(int indexL, int indexM, int indexH)
{        
    int mSize = indexH - indexL + 1;
    int* mergedData = new int[mSize];
    int mergedIndex = 0;
    int rightInd = indexM + 1;
    int leftInd = indexL;

    while(leftInd <= indexM && rightInd <= indexH){
        if(myArray[indexL] < myArray[rightInd]){
            mergedData[mergedIndex++] = myArray[leftInd++];
        }else{
            mergedData[mergedIndex++] = myArray[rightInd++];
        }
    }

    while(leftInd <= indexM){
        mergedData[mergedIndex++] = myArray[leftInd++];
    }
    while(rightInd <= indexH){
        mergedData[mergedIndex++] = myArray[rightInd++];
    }

    for(int i = indexL; i < indexH + 1; i++){
        myArray[i] = mergedData[i - indexL];
    }
    delete[] mergedData;

}

void Sort::Print(){
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        std::cout << " " << myArray[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: `#define __SORT__` That identifier is reserved. By defining it, your program will have undefined behaviour. You should use some other header guard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first check in your `if` is not right. Just because, e.g. input {8,4,100,7}, doesn't mean it's sorted due to `7 < 8`.

```
void Sort::MergeSort(int low, int high) {
    //base case
    if(myArray[high] <= myArray[low]){
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Oh perfect. After that change it's still only sorting half of the array. Here are my new results Unsorted:  7 49 73 58 30 72 44 78 23 9
Sorted:  7 49 73 30 58 9 23 44 72 78